# Flask: template not found when running on Travis

Tags: python, flask, pytest, travis-ci

I have an issue when making unit tests on my Flask application. The tests are running well locally, but fail when running on Travis CI.

I reproduced a minimal example in this repository: https://github.com/anth2o/flask_debug.
You can find the results of the run on Travis there: https://travis-ci.com/github/anth2o/flask_debug/builds/174345818

Comment: first check current working directory in flask and in test - `os.getcwd()` - test may runs in different folder - ie. `tests` - and it may search template in `tests/templates`

Comment: They are both executed at the root of my project, when I execute the test locally as well as on travis : https://travis-ci.com/github/anth2o/flask_debug/builds/174382198

Comment: did you check it ? Did you use `os.getcwd()` and/or `os.listdir()` to confirm that python runs it in folder which you expect? If code has problem to find folder then it has to run in wrong place

Comment: Yep, I checked it. In fact, I found out why the test was working locally and not on travis.
Locally, I installed my package by doint `pip install -e .` and  the test was working.
On my CI, I used `pip install .` and the test is failing

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find out what was the problem. As it is shown in my Makefile, I was installing my application in the CI with the command `pip install .`, which leads into an error `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound` during the unit test. The templates folder was not reachable.

However, I didn't not have this error locally, because I installed the package `pip install -e .`.

I didn't know that until now, but to deploy a Flask application with setuptools, you need to follow these guidelines: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/distribute/

In my [repo](https://github.com/anth2o/flask_debug/commits/master), my first commit was the state of my minimal example when it was failing on the CI. The second commit is the solution to this problem.